# CloudKit Get actual Object from Record ID in OSX

Tags: macos, cloudkit, cksubscription, cknotification

I am trying to use CKSubscription to subscribe to changes.  I am following Apple's docs which seems to be very general and incomplete. 
[Link to Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH8-SW1)

I have got the point of getting Record ID sent to my app via the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in `AppDelegate` and I have got my Record Id: using this code:

```
func application(application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let cknNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String:NSObject])

        if cknNotification.notificationType == .Query,
            let queryNotification = cknNotification as? CKQueryNotification {
            let recordId = queryNotification.recordID
            print(recordId)
        }
```

How do I convert the CKNotification into the Actual Object I stores in Cloudkit? Do I need to perform another fetch or is the data contained in the CKNotification that I just need to Cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I worked it out.

The Notification only lets you know that they have changed.  You need to do the work to pull the new records and update them. ( Makes sense really)

privateCloudDatabase().fetchRecordWithID(recordId!, completionHandler: { (recordfetched, error) in

```
            //Check the Record Type if multiple.. I only have one type.
   let myRecordType = recordfetched?.recordType
            let myObject = mySuperObject(record: recordfetched!)
            print("done")
        })
```

// I should probably add more optional checking - but above just illustrates the solution and how simple it is to get.